# Users should be able to redact sensitive information from their own questions or answers

Tags: feature-request, post-redaction

### Context:

I accidentally left some mildly sensitive information in a post.  In my case, I noticed it and edited the post quickly enough that it didn't end up in the revision history (thank you, implementers!).

But that led me to wonder what I'd do if I noticed later, and that led me to *[How to handle a publicly posted API key (or password, or other sensitive information)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258066/how-to-handle-a-publicly-posted-api-key-or-password-or-other-sensitive-informa)*.

### The Problem:

Currently, the only way to redact sensitive information from the revision history is to "Notify one of the site developers of the situation so that they can hard-delete the older revisions from the database itself."

Perhaps that's not a problem, but it seems like a nuisance for everybody.

### Proposed Solution:

It would be useful for duffers such as myself if the author of a question or reply could edit the revision history rather than go through a site developer.  (As a side matter, I wouldn't even know how to notify a site developer.)

Since such powers could be abused, perhaps that ability would be granted only to users with sufficient reputation.

Comment: Definitely has potential for abuse (students trying to avoid plagarism detection comes to mind).

Comment: When something is out on the internet, treat it as being permanently there. Redacting it here won't stop it's spread on copycat sites.

Comment: To add to what @simonzack said: you're *worse* off if we delete it here, because that may lull you into a false sense of security. Once your credentials have been exposed in any form, to anyone at all, for any length of time, you need to burn them and get new ones. Forget damage control altogether as a strategy.

Comment: I've been earning an average of minus 15 points per Meta question(!).  I'd like to think that's some sort of record, but it really means that I'm learning by asking, as it should be.  Thank you for the substantial and informative comments (honestly).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure there is any level of reputation that a tool like this would be appropriate for. This occurs *so infrequently* with higher-rep users that the reputation requirement wouldn't actually make much of a difference. For the most part we only see this kind of thing with newer users, and still not very often at that.

Even so, *permanently* removing information from the entire history of a post is a very serious matter that should not be taken so lightly. Not even moderators have the ability to do so, which is why we have to pass these flags onto the Stack Exchange team.

I know your reasoning for it is just removing login credentials, but there are a lot of other scenarios out there that would crop up. Users already try to remove their content for silly reasons. Students edit out code form the questions to prevent plagiarism warnings when they turn in their assignments, random users will remove everything from their question if it's been "solved", and angry users will try to delete all their posts as part of a rage-quit. We certainly don't want them to have any sort of ability to completely remove all the content and leave no trace, no way for us to put it back if it was done incorrectly.

This is why the Stack Exchange team prefers to handle it themselves. It lets them evaluate things on a case-by-case basis and make sure it's being used appropriately.

**As an aside:** the generally preferred way to have a revision burned is to just flag it for a moderator. We can easily pass it along to the team for you as we are frequently in contact with them.

Comment: One *could* think about a special flag on the revision-history, which temporarily removes all but the newest (at that time) revision from observation (the flag should get priority for mods, and have a severe penalty when declined instead of handed to the devs). Though, if it really happens so seldom, that might be too much work for the gain.

Comment: I don't know the actual numbers, but I usually only see one or two per week. To put it in a better perspective: we pass on a *lot* more messages to have fraudulent votes invalidated than we do to have revisions burned.

Comment: @animuson: Thank you.  You have confirmed my thought that "Perhaps that's not a problem..." as not being a problem.

Comment: It's worth noting that now it only takes 2 moderators to do a redaction, instead of requiring staff.