# I can't submit a duplicate of a deleted question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I submitted a question around 12 hours ago, and I didn't get my desired answer. Being (very) new to Stack Overflow, I submitted another very similar question immediately after. I got a comment telling me that it was basically a duplicate (which it was - sorry!), so I decided to delete both questions and submit another one. I deleted them, but now when I try to submit the question again for an answer, it tells me that it appears to be a duplicate of the question I have deleted. Can you not submit duplicates of deleted questions?

Comment: Reposting is impolite at best on any site I've ever visited. Why oh why do you think it should be appropriate here?

Comment: Why would you think that the way to resolve being told it's inappropriate to post a duplicate of your original question was to delete the duplicate *and the original* and post **another duplicate**? What was wrong with the orignal, other than that you had decided it wasn't getting answers fast enough?

Comment: @sphanley Someone on the original downvoted it and told me I clearly didn't want any help, and then stopped responding, so I thought the only way to get an answer was to ask again.  Also, in the first question, people assumed I knew to run everything in Terminal, which at the time I didn't know.  The second provided a better warning that I was technologically inept.  Not true, but I figured I'd get spoon fed the answers.  I was wrong, and I already apologized for that up top.  I'm sorry, I made a mistake.  I will no longer post duplicates.  This has been a learning experience.

Comment: Drew it seems it would be worth your time to explore how things work here a bit more. E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And the following, on what are considered the most important "rules": http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans. Basically, posting the same thing over and over is considered bad etiquette (there is a reason it was not answered the first time). If you need to change the question, then edit it. Don't delete and post another one. That contributes to noise.

Comment: Remember you have a bunch of smart, talented, often rather well paid people here volunteering their time because they love code and enjoy helping people. It falls to the OP to learn a little about how things work before blundering in.

Comment: your original question may not have been up to scratch, but this one on meta is. don't worry about it, everyone makes mistakes and while others have said read the faq, I must point out that the site posessing an FAQ is not proof against normal honest people making mistakes, even when they do read it. Atleast you had the character to own it and try to sort it out. well done, chap.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You've pretty much hit the nail on the head. This is likely due to the fact that a deleted question is really just soft-deleted. If a user with more than 10k rep, or the original author, has a link to the question, they can still view it. Diamond mods can see these directly from your profile.

I suggest you undelete one of the two questions and edit in to shape. Be patient, as it can take a couple days or even a couple weeks to get an answer to your question. Editing a question will bump it to the top of the active list and draw more attention to it. Please be sure any edits you make are significant improvements to formatting or clarity, as users will get annoyed if you continually bump your post with small, meaningless edits. Posting the same question multiple times is frowned upon here, and will get the repeat questions closed as duplicates and likely deleted.

To view a recently deleted question, go to your question list and scroll to the bottom. You should see a link to your recently deleted questions there.

Do be aware that downvoted questions that you delete will *still* count against you in the question ban algorithm, so deleting and reasking a poorly received question is not a way to avoid a question ban. The deleted questions won't count more than if they were undeleted, but they won't count less either.

Comment: `undelete one of the two questions and edit in to shape` - I believe you can edit it _then_ undelete it, right?  (Just to keep users from downvoting/etc during the edit while it's still in bad shape)

Comment: *"Do be aware that deleting questions could potentially lead you to a question ban"* I don't think deleting questions actually *causes* the ban; it's just that deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) still count toward a ban if you're already on your way to one. Anyway, this won't apply to most users now that there is [rate limiting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243460/rolling-question-rate-limits-are-now-network-wide) to slow them down long before they get into ban territory.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot "Deleted posts are mostly irrelevant to the question ban... What matters are _poorly-received_ posts..." ([Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601))

Comment: @gnat That's exactly what I said.

Answer (score 20):

Think of it this way - why should you be able to post a duplicate of your own post that you just deleted? Deleting a question implies that there's some reason it shouldn't be here. There's two possible cases here:

If it's deleted because it's not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow, then it shouldn't be reposted.

If it *is* an appropriate, on-topic question here and you want it answered, then the first instance of you asking it ought to be undeleted.

Asking, deleting and reposting a question would at best essentially just let people spam their question to the top of the list, and at worst would let people keep replacing downvoted posts with "clean" versions (at least until it got them a question ban). The appropriate thing to do when told that you shouldn't duplicate your original question would be to just remove your duplicate and leave it at that, not try to hide the original and then keep duplicating away.

Comment: Even if you clean your question up into something that could serve as the canonical good question, it will still contain the downvotes and comments left when it was in its initial state. The comments might not make sense anymore, and the downvotes keep it from showing up on anyone's active list, making the question permanently tainted. Unfortunately I don't see a good way around it.

Comment: If question revision has made a comment no longer make sense, there's a comment flag reason which is "Obsolete" that can be used to get outdated  comments removed. You can even request a moderator purges the entire comments thread if it's all obsolete. But the real "way around it" is to just make sure that you're posting a high quality question the first time around, rather than only improving your post if you *have to* to get an answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom If the OP doesn't get a satisfactory answer within two days, they can put a bounty on the question (they currently have just enough rep to do so).

Comment: @SamHanley What if you put something in your post you don't want others seeing so you deleted it and made a new post. And the edit it argument doesn't work in this case as you can see previous edits etc. What do you do then?

Comment: @AidanelGoste in that case, rather than deleting the question (in which case any user with > 10k rep can still see it), you should submit a custom flag and ask for the problematic revisions to be manually removed. See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258066/how-to-handle-a-publicly-posted-api-key-or-password-or-other-sensitive-informa) for more details.