# How do I get my post deleted as quickly as possible since it is someone's intellectual property?

Tags: support, post-redaction

Suppose I posted a question on Stack Overflow which includes a code snippet, and I got some answers to the question. And now an acquaintance of mine claims that the code example is his intellectual property (IP) and demands that I delete the question as soon as possible (or else...).

How would I do so, preferably without drawing attention to it (since I wouldn't want to emphasize that this specific code is intellectual property)?

Answer (score 80):

I'm glad you asked this, since it comes up a lot in support emails and flags.

The answer probably isn't as simple as you'd like... So let's walk our way through it:

### First, take responsibility for the situation

You've posted something you shouldn't have. Maybe you're violating someone else's rights, or maybe you're just running the risk of getting caught cheating on your homework... But either way, that's **your** doing - it's not the fault of Stack Overflow, of the moderators, or of the folks who took the time to help you with your problem... So getting mad at any of them isn't a good idea. You need their help, and admitting you screwed up and are willing to put some effort into fixing the problem you caused is a good first step in getting that help.

### Next, edit your question

You don't have the right to delete an answered question, but you *can* edit out the bits that might get you into trouble... However, ***don't vandalize the question!*** When you're done editing, it must still be a valid question and answers that were correct and helpful before you edited must still be correct and helpful. To this end,

1. **Remove extraneous code**. This is a good idea anyway, but if you didn't do it before it's not too late. Aim for [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - just enough code to allow readers to identify and reproduce the problem. Since the question has already been answered, you should have a pretty good idea of which logic actually caused the problem, so you can eliminate just about everything else.
2. **Replace proprietary logic**. This *should* have already happened in #1, but if you have a big chunk of code that implements some proprietary business process which isn't yours and will get you fired, try to replace it with a less sensitive bit of logic that you wrote yourself which still exhibits the problem you needed to solve. This may not be easy; take your time and do it right. Remember, **you** posted this - the folks who took the time to answer had no way of knowing you shouldn't have.
3. **Rename identifying symbols**. For instance, if the name of your function is `UmbrellaCorp.DoEvil()` rename it to `MyCorp.DoStuff()`; if the name of your library is `CS301FinalProject` then maybe go with `DataManipulation` instead. Most of the time, this is all anyone's really concerned about anyway.

### Then edit the answers so that they remain consistent with your edited question

If you renamed symbols or removed extraneous code, you may need to edit code references or quotes in the answers so that they make sense. Take your time - you're modifying others' work here, and you want the results to look good. Explain what you're doing and why in the revision comments. Remember, you're relying on the goodwill of the folks who already went out of their way to help you - if you make them look bad, they'll roll back your edit and probably flag a moderator saying you're vandalizing their work. Be respectful, be polite, and be thorough.

### Finally, ask a moderator to redact the revisions.

You'll have to flag each post you modified and explain in detail what's going on. See: [How to handle a publicly posted API key (or password, or other sensitive information)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258066/how-to-handle-a-publicly-posted-api-key-or-password-or-other-sensitive-informa)

Once done, this will hide the original post(s) from anyone other than employees who might wish to view them.

### Alternately: file a DMCA report

I don't really recommend this for most situations, but if you find that *someone else* has posted your work without your permission in violation of your copyright, you may request that the posts be removed in accordance with US law. See: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#copyright

If, for example, you post your employer's code without their permission, and are unable or unwilling to remove it yourself, they may take advantage of this policy to remove your posts from the site.

Comment: The preferred route takes probably a couple of hours at most. How much time is needed to process a DMCA report? Because the question asks for *as quickly as possible* and AFAIK bureaucracy doesn't come with speed.

Comment: We've spent weeks - I kid you not - going back and forth with folks over edits. The process I laid out here *should* be relatively quick and easy, but... You do have to actually want to make it work. From what I've seen, in the bulk of these requests DMCA is completely inapplicable anyway, since there's no copyright violation... It's just students trying to avoid getting caught cheating, and they're often *not* very receptive to guidance nor particularly inclined to respect the work others have put into their posts. Thus my desire to have something we can refer to instead of arguing with them.

Comment: This post reminded me of a question I wanted to ask: How often, if ever, does someone follow Step 1?

Comment: I don't have numbers on that, @QPaysTaxes. It does happen. Not as often as it should.

Comment: @Shog i wasn't interested in numbers, just curious if people often got mad at SE for storing data when they out it there. Thanks!

Comment: You're unsure if folks ever blame others for their own mistakes and get furiously angry when told they have to fix things themselves? Bless you... Yes, yes they do do that.

Comment: Great answer @Shog9 +1

Comment: @Shog9 I'd add mention of being sure to explain in the edit comments why you are changing all the answers because if they get reviewed you'd want people to understand.

Comment: *"Explain what you're doing and why in the revision comments."* @ArtB

Comment: @Shog9 Do you remember that time that a contractor posted a company's exchange server admin password and login and ip on a question on serverfault?

Comment: I'm sure that's happened more than once, @magisch. Mods will generally redact them as a courtesy, though of course you can never trust that they won't be used after that by someone who caught it in the interim.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this is one of the best moderator posts on meta, ever.  Thanks @Shog9.