# Are all generative AIs banned?

Tags: discussion, answers, chatgpt

I recently came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75292142/20384561). [The answer has since been deleted - [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNhG6.png)]. The answerer's profile acknowledges that

> We are an AI Generated response community, we are real humans who want to help people.

The answer has an explanation and code at the top, while at the bottom, a boldface section states "**human here:**", and then gives further info. When reading through the ChatGPT ban question, I saw that even part of a question being generated by ChatGPT is unacceptable. However, this answer appears to likely have been generated by another AI, perhaps something like [Blenderbot](https://blenderbot.ai). Is this acceptable, or are all answers generated by AI banned on Stack Overflow? According to [this Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy), all

> contributions generated by GPT most often do not meet these standards and therefore are not contributing to a trustworthy environment.

However, the article also states that

> This trust is broken when users copy and paste information into answers without validating that the answer provided by GPT is correct, ensuring that the sources used in the answer are properly cited (a service GPT does not provide), and verifying that the answer provided by GPT clearly and concisely answers the question asked.

With the human input in the question as well, this would imply that this answer was reviewed by a human, and therefore has been validated.

### Summary

Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75292142/20384561) (now deleted: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNhG6.png)) allowed at all on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Anyone concerned that the fluff at the end also implies, the account is used by multiple carbon based lifeforms, and thus itself likely a violation of the rules?

Comment: [CEO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/01/31/ceo-update-eliminating-obstacles-to-productivity-efficiency-and-learning/): *"We’re excited about the possibilities generative AI may hold for the public platform as it matures, and we look forward to experimentation around it."*

Comment: Please note that ChatGPT is only temporarily banned. This may suggest that there may be conditions that would make the use of these tools ok, if only they would fulfill them. Since there is probably nothing special about ChatGPT any AI that fulfills these conditions (being better than the average human answerer here maybe?) might be okay.

Comment: I wouldn't discard the person who asks and the person who answers (in this case) are the same (or somehow closely related).

Comment: @AmoskalescapingfromRussia I see no real reason for this suspicion.

Comment: "Creative AIs - YouTube › @CreativeAIs › about
Welcome to our channel, where we explore the exciting world of AI-generated content! Our focus is on showcasing how technology like ChatGPT" can... blah blah blah. Same ol'. Nothing to see here. Closing this as a duplicate. If you want to discuss using ChatGPT and its related ban, then do so at the proper post.

Comment: On a broader note, the notion of "generative ai's" is not an emerging field so much as decades of existing work culminating in the transformer algorithm that we are seeing right now. There are no instances of this in practice aside from ChatGPT due to its complexity. Google's think tank came up with it, and there will be an iteration on the design from Google themselves in the future. These implementations will be few and far between, they should be addressed individually (as ChatGPT was).

Comment: Specialization cannot be duplicate of generalization but do whatever you want.

Comment: They [want to](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21114123/creative-ais) turn Stack Overflow into a help desk (some will argue it already effectively is). (The user profile text has now been changed, but [the meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422949/are-all-generative-ais-banned/422951#422951) is still here.)

Comment: The relevant part of the profile text was (slightly edited): *"We are an AI-generated response community. We are real humans who want to help people who don't usually get responses or the respect they deserve on Stack Overflow, and we believe there are no stupid questions. Disclaimer: We do not script this process even though it is possible we believe bots are a problem on the Internet nowadays. While it is interesting and might save time, we believe in the importance of the human element."*.

Comment: why is this closed as a duplicate? it's not a duplicate of the associated question.

Comment: Overruling 5 users to re-close this as a duplicate is inappropriate.   This is false: "This question already has answers here:  Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned"
"Are all generative AIs banned?" is NOT answered there.  Also, discussion there is locked.  It even says to open other questions tagged chatgpt, but then such questions are closed?  Where's the sense in that?  
The (definition in the) policy should be broadened to include GPTs in general / all LLMs (Large Language Models) including Anthropic's Claude.  IMO.

Comment: There's agreement at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252131/discussion-on-temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This has not been adequately validated by a human, and thus it violates our rules on pasting AI-generated content without validating it.  We can't verify exactly which AI system generated a piece of content, but we can often tell when someone is using one.

Consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75292142/208273).  It's obviously nonfunctional at a glance.  This isn't valid Python, because the indentation is wrong:

```python
#get the indices for each common value in lhs and rhs grouping variables
for group in common:
lhs_idx = np.where(lhs_grouping_var == group)
rhs_idx = np.where(rhs_grouping_var == group)
for l in lhs_idx[0]:
for r in rhs_idx[0]:
if len(lhs_data[l]['word']) == len(rhs_data[r]['word']):
print(lhs_data[l]['lhs_id'], lhs_data[l]['word'], rhs_data[r]['rhs_id'], rhs_data[r]['word'])
```

There is also [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75291801/208273) that needed to be edited due to answering the wrong question and being called out in the comments.

This exemplifies exactly why we don't allow this sort of content: it's easy to let errors slip past, and the work required to catch them is time-consuming.

Comment: can you please clarify: is material  from all AIs banned or just ChatGPT?  If it's all, then my comment to Creative is, well, wrong

Comment: Well the official post only mentions ChatGPT, no other AIs.

Comment: @cafce25 that my reading too.  This answer kinda/sorta/maybe implies a broader ban, so I'd like an official/mod confirmation

Comment: We're discussing the broader policy internally; at this stage, it's not _exactly_ per-se banned beyond just ChatGPT, but it's also worth noting that we're unlikely to be able to tell the difference between ChatGPT and any other large language model (and "oh it was actually GPT-3" or similar is unlikely to result in the mod action being reversed).  We also will currently take action against anyone posting content from any AI without verifying its accuracy (as we would for anyone posting content from _any_ source without regard to its accuracy).

Comment: Re *"it's easy to let errors slip past, and the work required to catch them is time-consuming."*: Yes, this was already a problem before ChatGPT ("answers" by mindless plagiarisers). Who is going to check code dumps? (Yes, that is a rhetorical question.)

Comment: "it's not exactly per-se banned beyond just ChatGPT" this part (and the whole comment) should maybe also be part of the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure wrongly indented Python is a good indication of an AI generated post

Comment: @DavidW It's not (and I don't intend to suggest otherwise in this post).  But it's an indication that the poster didn't check the answer to make sure it worked (and indeed, the poster here has confirmed in a now-deleted comment that they "didn't run the code to double check it was functional").

Comment: "Consider this answer. It's obviously nonfunctional at a glance." Aside from that, the human commentary **doesn't relate to the code**; it's commenting about reasons not to use Python (which would normally be edited out of any other answer for a Python question anyway; it's an off-topic rant, even if not written with ranting tone) followed by advertising for the AI service in question (flaggable as spam even if it weren't anything to do with AI). Also, the [user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21114123/unknowndrone) indicates a clear intent to circumvent Stack Overflow policy.

Comment: @Karl They've edited their profile now and seem to have removed the "clear intent to circumvent Stack Overflow policy" but also quoted you on that, which I don't understand.

Comment: Strange that someone in that position is familiar enough with Meta etc. to do that....

Comment: To note, that user was using ChatGPT to generate their code. There is no other source at the moment of generative AI... for now.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I may be wrong, but the tone of their profile edit and the fact that they did check meta seem to indicate it was an unintended mistake they immediately regretted. Since SO automatically encourages people to be kind to newbies posting their first answer, maybe they shouldn't have been too harsh if they were. But I'd like to stress "if they were" because I can't tell if that was the case, since archive.org doesn't have their answer archived.

Comment: In any case, I'm left wondering if quoted wrong answers shouldn't be anonymized in order to prevent unnecessary public attention, while addressing whatever issues the posts may have within the scope of the specific question-answer, or even privately. That's always under the assumption of good faith, if it's proved that's not the case, then maybe a sanction is due instead.

Answer (score 31):

> Are all Generative AIs banned?

Yes and no, but mostly yes.

AI is becoming more ubiquitous in our daily lives. It can also be a useful tool for a developer, if the AI is smart enough and the developer is smart enough. So far AI hasn't replaced the developer and that's unlikely to happen soon. We do not ask AIs to develop apps for us. AI also cannot come up with new ideas on its own - it does what it was programmed to do in the capacity that we ask it to. So the question is where is it allowed to alleviate our lives and where it would be unwise to let it take over the wheel.

I use [Tabnine](https://www.tabnine.com/) for predictive typing. It's actually very useful and improves my coding skills. But it doesn't do the job for me. It also doesn't make me a better developer. Whenever Tabnine suggests something, I have to validate whether it's actually what I want and whether it will work. I still am the author of the code written this way, the ideas behind it, and I have the knowledge of how it works. The AI helped me write the code based on the context, other projects and my coding style. It can even suggest variable/function names and write comments. But it's just a tool and it's not infallible. If I am not careful, my reliance on it could be source of bugs and broken software (e.g. Tabnine removed an s from a word it thought should not be plural leading to an error).

I have [Grammarly](https://app.grammarly.com/) installed in my browser. It helps me avoid typographical and grammatical errors when writing any text. It's extremely useful to generate clear and concise sentences. But it doesn't do the writing for me. My incoherent thoughts are simply written in proper English.

So, AI has a place on Stack Overflow: it can helps us write code examples and their explanation. But it shouldn't replace us! At least not just yet. Any answer you post must be your work - written by you, with the help of AI tools if you wish so. We want **you** to share **your** knowledge, not some regurgitated content generated by AI.

An AI cannot be allowed to post answers by itself. It is too imperfect and goes against the idea of Stack Overflow as a website: to share information by experienced developers.

---

There's also the topic of plagiarism. Any content not of your own must be [properly attributed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). If the whole answer was written by AI without your input then YOU ARE NOT THE AUTHOR. An answer cannot be composed of just a quote - it may be deleted by mods. If you wish to quote something generated by AI in your answer, you may do so, assuming it's properly quoted and it doesn't constitute the core of your post.

Comment: "it can helps us write": a perfect example of why you should not rely on such tools, without reviewing the results.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I saw that too, couldn't help but think it was left in on purpose.

Comment: "Yes and no, but mostly yes." I love clear answers. In that regard I would suggest that the answer to "Are all..." must be "No" without any additions as long as there is one example to the contrary or simply "Yes" otherwise. It's okay to then continue with "But most are..." or "But using them as support is okay" or whatever.

Comment: "If the whole answer was written by AI without your input then YOU ARE NOT THE AUTHOR"... but for something like GitHub Copilot, you give input in the context, and it definitely makes you the author, assuming the answer was generated on the spot and not stolen from some source.

Comment: I mean legally, it makes you the author. in other respects one might think differently.

Answer (score 29):

*sighs in human*

So there's already been a lot of great ground covered, and while [the OP has posted an answer defending their actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422951/1079354), this gets back to the root of why people [so *desperately* want to turn to AI to help them with their questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422554/1079354).

## People want their questions answered.

That's it.  That's the ***whole point*** of this.

People just want to get an answer to their question.  They're stuck somewhere and they want their question answered.  [They don't have the patience for the prose or the rules or the structure or the ceremony or *any of that B.S.* we put in front of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374637/1079354), since it's a barrier to getting their question answered.

The flip side to this is that *people want to help people*.  I could [point to this infamous diagram](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/1079354) as a quick reference - or the wall on which the writing was plastered on originally - but this is and will continue to be the nature of how Q&A functions.

Someone has a question.  Someone wants to answer.

The obvious problems are:

- Skill gap in both directions - someone [who doesn't really know what they're asking about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364282/1079354) may not benefit from or value the help we give them, and we haven't even ***begun*** to speak about someone who's just spouting *incorrect nonsense* in their answers
- Abandoning ceremony - our rules, either spoken or unspoken, can always be distilled to someone asking a question that is clear and has enough information in it to either be answered or closed as a duplicate
- Stigma of downvotes and closure - no one likes being told that they're bad or that they didn't search well enough, but both of these things exist to help the <s>community-at-large with determining if a question is good or if an answer is helpful</s> the company build products and services on top of Stack Overflow's reputation alone

---

So is this kind of style OK? An OP uses an AI-based answer and then provides human context to it?

***Hell* no!**

The biggest and most glaring issue is that it fails its noble intent - [**by providing incomplete, bad or wrong information, you do not help anyone.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421856/1079354)  It can be compounded by giving someone bad information in a niche technology in which the subject matter experts are scarce and *cannot* provide timely correction.

There's also the matter of being able to republish what you post.  If you don't own it, or don't have permission to share it, you can't contribute it under CC-by-SA.  (This is also one of many reasons why people scramble to delete otherwise sensible-looking questions because [they didn't have the permission from their employer to post it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327145/1079354))

All that noise about how this is gonna lead to the death of Stack Overflow or how it's "inevitable" is just that - ***noise***.  Ain't nothing stopping people who desire an AI-driven experience from just building their own damn site and flooding it with AI-based answers.  Problem is that they *know* that it's not going to be practical since there's no one around to ensure that they're actually doing the right thing.  At *best* this means that someone copies broken code into their project, and at *worst* this makes its way into our banking systems.  I can only hope that we who are employed enforce stringent and rigorous code reviews to be sure that things like this don't gravely impact us.

Comment: "People want their questions answered." - that may be true for the person who asks. Other people want to answer questions (help vampires or what we call them), or maybe just gain reputation because it makes them feel and look good (rep whores). These two groups benefit a lot from AI generated content.

Comment: "They don't have the patience for the prose or the rules or the structure or the ceremony or any of that B.S. we put in front of them, since it's a barrier to getting their question answered." They may perceive it this way, but actually, failure to observe these "ceremonies" _is_ the barrier to getting their question answered, or at least should continue to be, if we care at all about building a quality community resource.

Comment: @ggorlen:  Yes, you make my point.  We intentionally put the barriers in front of the user.  The user then dances around those barriers.  They run into friction in both cases because people just want their question answered.  Do *I* care if they run into friction?  Not particularly, but the people who want their question answered very much care.  The company also purports to care but for the life of me I can't entirely put my full stock of faith into that...

Answer (score -6):

In theory, yes.

In practice, all except the one under secret development

Comment: Bold of you to assume there's only one.

Comment: Bolder of you to assume that "the one under secret development" Is not *also* banned.

Answer (score -48):

I have been going over what everyone has said, and I think there is a good solution. Since everyone seems to think my idea was to hurt the community, I will give my solution to the problem. I will let you all deem if it is a good idea or not, in relation to the issue on Plagiarism and AI. There has been research done that you can identify users through their style of code. Here is a link for the article https://www.wired.com/story/machine-learning-identify-anonymous-code/

That brings in my solution, stack overflow should train and implement a precheck for things tagged in code. Since the AI has been trained on so many people it is likely to have a general / changing  style, and have a lower success rate than what the article states. There might be false positives; however, if we give users the option to be able to tag AI generated code, and have it show the section to everyone else which part is AI generated. We can kill two birds with one stone so to speak. Things in the AI tag do not get scanned or flagged, and people know what sections were generated. This means it would be easy to see if AI held the **core** of the work. On top of that you can also decrease copy and paste code as you could match coding styles with users. There are obviously privacy concerns with something like this. For example what if two users have the same style? This would most likely point to them being the same person. I personally think this is a good thing, as people cant pretend to be two users but what do I know? I got flamed for my AI idea. Anyway since code is going to get scanned anyway, you could also build up a subsystem to check for similar questions asked. This was another issue I noticed being mentioned in duplicate questions. Also users with high enough scores or certain badges could force bypass a flag if it was a false positive. Meaning more power for the community for what gets posted.

The reality is, I don't fully know stack overflows processing power / budget and if this is something possible for them. This is a question of if the community wants it and if stack overflow can afford it. Technologically this is possible, at least to a level of reasonable accuracy.

Anyway food for thought :)

Since I am being discussed, I figured I'd at least address this myself.

1. The reason the end tag / Human: is added to every post is so people understand it is a combination of an AI/human response. I am not taking credit for something I did not fully do myself.
2. If an answer is incorrect, I adjust it, fix it and try to give people another improved rendition to better meet their requirements. How is this any different than a real software development job? Most of you probably have GitHub [GitHub Copilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub_Copilot) installed in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code). Also, errors naturally happen in code and sometimes it breaks or doesn't work and if you say this never happens to you, great, you're the 0.001%.
3. I have a background in numerical analysis, AI, and software development. So I only answer questions I feel I can personally answer if something doesn’t work.
4. If you want to ban me for this, I won’t be mad. I completely understand. If a moderator wants to tell me simply not to post I won’t. I will save you the time to ban me.

Finally, the world will be changing over the course of the next 15 years. It's only going to lead to the death of Stack Overflow in the future, if this is not accounted for. Which I personally would never want to see happen, because I think this is one of, if not, the best sites out there.

I intended to help the community, not hinder it, so I want to apologize for that. Thank you everyone for at least hearing me out; some of you made very valid points. I have decided I will no longer answer questions, because I do not want to harm the community. I will continue to wish for the success of Stack Overflow and I hope all of you that read this the best of luck. :) "It was a short time but a good time" -- unknown

Okay, I was not going to edit this anymore, but I do think a few more things need to be addressed. I ended up staying awake to answer respond back to people, so while I was tired, I did start to get slightly annoyed with two users, one I never responded back to and one I did. Also I was not being/trying to be "passive aggressive"; I was overtired and was genuinely trying to be respectful. I felt for a few users it was more of a witch hunt as they never directly responded to my question.

> If "I" rent a cloud machine, and "I" train a huge model based on relevant research papers dealing in word prediction then "I" prompt that model. Who owns the content?"

This is a genuine question, I feel like got glossed over.

As for why I say we, the YouTube channel is run by me and a few people. I know some of them program, and some of them don't. The ones that do program didn’t currently want to be part of this Stack Overflow thing I was doing because honestly they see it as a waste of time. I have seen it as helping people.

I used **We** because creative AIs is a community thing; it’s not just me. Since no one I work with on the video side of things wanted to help with Stack Overflow, I was going to continue to look for people to join and help. Clearly this community just started, but it takes time to grow...

The reason I said I was not doing questions anymore is because if I am not allowed to fully answer with AI and respond as a human: it defeats the entire purpose of this account. I was not saying I would never personally answer questions, but with the way you all dogpile your assumptions instead of asking for extra clarification, I can't say it motivates me to. This is why Stack Overflow is seen as one of the most toxic communities. I responded back to a few people who never even got a response until this post got posted in meta. So I figured even an AI response is better than none, and if the OP said there were issues, I’d address it with the OP, not all of Stack Overflow. If someone asked thought-provoking questions they would most likely get thought-provoking answers. If people are going going to be accusatory with "plagiarism" claims, it is human nature to be defensive. I simply wanted to be transparent, and I did not want to make promises I might not have been able to keep. Promises such as there will be no more mistakes, etc.

Okay, I am confused if you all are venting, not reading, or confused because I deleted my responses.

> Considering the changes to the OP's profile, it seems that they actually had no intention of learning from their mistakes, or understanding the reasons why their content wasn't allowed.

This is a mix of not reading and me probably deleting my responses. I will address the part I deleted. I agreed that this is against policy, and it has clearly been stated.

> If you wish to quote something generated by AI in your answer, you may do so, assuming it's properly quoted and it doesn't constitute the **core** of your post.

I responded to this above in response to that and many similar things.

> The reason I said I was not doing questions anymore is because if I am not allowed to fully answer with AI and respond as a human: it defeats the entire purpose of this account. I was not saying I would never personally answer questions

In conclusion, I understand, I learned, and I removed the account, my bio is not a reflection of the policy, but of the people.

> I think you miss one important point: the AI ban isn't because it is AI. No one has something against useful tools.

Once again, I did not miss the point and I understand why. I was ignorant to the rules, and I made a mistake. I thought I was doing something to help out. A few users made rational arguments on how it can lead to more work and I agree.

> yet you want to cry persecution that we're "not welcoming". IMO this is the experience of 100% of people who claim that SO is "toxic" -- you're just upset you weren't allowed to participate your way

I am not "upset", I am not "crying" and I am not going to repeat myself for the 100th time, stating that I agree with the policy.

> Coming back to this discussion the next day, and in light of the sob-story you've posted to your profile

My bio isn't some "sob-story"; it's to help convey the importance of conversation, and behaving like a real person. Instead of saying accusatory statements

> I feel like the intention was never to help people or contribute meaningfully to Stack Overflow. You just wanted somewhere to experiment with your AI and are upset we don't want to be your guinea pigs.

Oh, the irony...

Comment: Apropos 1) I think the bigger problem is the AI does not credit it's sources.

Comment: You make a reasonable argument, @CreativeArts. The problem is that it is evident that you did not adequately vet the content produced by your AI before posting it. I think if you had done so and done so regularly, we might be having a different discussion.

Comment: The reason AI generated answers are banned is that it takes a lot of community effort to correct them/remove them, and unfortunately we see many AI generated answers with lots of basic errors. If the AI generating the answers gets better in the future, maybe we'll have another discussion about that on meta then! :)

Comment: Yes errors happen but blatant errors like for example the one Ryan points out are not acceptable imo. Also at least 2/5 definitely wrong inital answers is just terrible.

Comment: When you include material in an answer that is not your own work, you are required to 1) make it clear what material is not your work by making it a quote block, and 2) explicitly state and link to where you copied it from, and 3) copied material should not form the entire answer.  Failure to follow these requirements leaves you open to claims of plagiarism.   You're part way there, but you need to get the whole way there.  This is independent of any specific AI content ban.  So if it's from ChatGPT, don't post it.  ( to be continued)

Comment: (Continued) If it's from another AI, and you have verified it, and attributed it , and include evidence of your verification,  you might be OK.  Others might still have a problem with it though

Comment: Separately from all of the above and the rest of the discussion: Thank you for weighing in.  It's important that we get a variety of perspectives on how and whether it might be possible for AI-generated content to exist responsibly within this ecosystem.

Comment: The problem isn't a wrong answer here or there, but the rate of wrong answers, unfortunately AIs provide code which often is far too believable and hard to verify, and as evidenced by your record many errors do slip through.

Comment: @CreativeAIs re _While I agree 99% of all AI tools do not require exact acknowledgement_. It's SO's rules that require you to attribute material that's not your own. That apples to all sources, AI or otherwise.  If by that phrase  you are referring to the AI's T&Cs. that's irrelevant to SO

Comment: As far as takeaways go, I would say that it's a serious problem to not run the solution at all, or even skim it closely enough to catch the indentation problems (I spotted it immediately, and I barely use Python).  I think any policy allowing use of AI assistance in creating solutions is going to require reasonable diligence on the part of the poster to catch basic problems in the answers.

Comment: I think the real issue is not making any attempt to fix issues. If you had vetted and fixed them _before_ or _soon after_ posting, I'd probably be on your side -- why should it matter where the basic parts of your answer come from? However you _are_ blindly using AI in this case, and it falls on the rest of Stack Overflow to correct you. Since you correctly identify that there are lots of wrong answers on Stack Overflow, it would be nice of you not to add some more :) Note that _your_ contributions from your background in numerical analysis, AI, and software development are welcome!

Comment: Some bottom lines here: 1) if a post breaches the plagiarism standards,  the post should be deleted and the OP sanctioned. 2) if a post breaches a specific ban (eg ChatGPT) the post should be deleted and the OP sanctioned.  3)  if a post doesn't fall under either of those criteria (or other sanctionable categories eg R/A or spam) it's subject to the usual commity curation,  including up/down votes.  Being wrong (in spite of the OPs attempts at validation) makes a post not useful

Comment: @CreativeAIs I suspect it's not actually your AI, but I'll play along.  If you've created an AI and asked it questions and posted answers based on its output, then in addition to everything I've already said, you are bound by the requirements for disclosing affiliation with the source, lest you be accused of undisclosed self promotion

Comment: *"no worries I wont be posting anymore"* No one is suggesting, or saying, that you shouldn't be posting any more, so this honestly feels like the wrong conclusion. User contributions are very welcome here, but that's just it; they should be from *you*, not an AI. If you truly do, as your profile suggests, want to help people, and have experience developing AI based applications, then your knowledge could be very helpful both on [so] and [ai.se], but (again) those contributions should be written byu yourself, not the AI you have created.

Comment: _"if you are banning people for incorrect answers there is a lot of banning that needs to get done. Because I would be bold enough to say there is a high volume of incorrect answers on this website."_ if anything, this should be an argument against doing anything which _exacerbates the very same problem_.

Comment: "its only going to lead to the death of stack overflow in the future" - people who want Stack Overflow to be exactly like any other website tend to make that prediction without any kind of data to back it up. But the whole reason for Stack Overflow to exist and thrive is because it decided to fill a hole NOT filled by the rest of the web. It goes left where everyone goes right on purpose.

Comment: You say "***we***" in your Profile, are there other Users/Accounts on SO from your "AI Collective" posting the same kind of Answers (in their respective Fields of Expertise), and are they going to stop from this Discussion (and remove their Answers), or does the Community have to "spot" and discover them before they will stop...? (We don't need the same "Discussion" with all of them, if you are not alone...)

Comment: Your answer started off great, but the passive-aggressive tone you switched to after your 4 points really isn't helping your cause...

Comment: Re *"I have a background in numerical analysis, AI, and software development"*: That doesn't jive with not being able to tell if [Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75292142/63550) is obviously syntactically incorrect (missing indentation)

Comment: Re *"I will just put more time and effort into my videos"*: Unless that is the point of it, the [monotone computer voice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nidZ7xGxn9Q) could be improved. Look at AI-generated YouTube channels like 'Future Unity'. The actual content is useless (it could be been said in a single sentence and in less than 20 seconds), but the production value is very high. Also, their clickbait titles are ***very very*** good. Instead of VeRY WeiRD (and irritating) cApitAliasTIon, they have titles of the form *"XXXX's terrifying new discovery that changes everything!"* ...

Comment: cont' - or *"XXXXXX's all new YYYYYY breakthrough shocks the entire industry!"*. Who can resist that?

Comment: \*cApitAlisaTIon

Comment: "_Finally, if you all want to get caught in 'group think' because you can't understand the world is changing that is fine._" This struck me as unnecessarily combative.

Comment: _"The world is going to be changing and if you wanna be those old men talking about kids and these "Phones" go ahead."_  I'd suggest you drop this typical evangelical / fanboy rhetoric. In my opinion, you're immensely overestimating the impact ChatGPT (and to a lesser extent, AI in general) has. You're not going to win any favor in this discussion with a "impending doom" attitude like that. Argue with facts, not with idle (and frankly insulting) speculation.

Comment: Remember when blockchain was the future of the web?

Comment: Post only content that from your own knowledge is correct & give credit for what you didn't do--no other meta content. That is all there is to it.

Comment: No one's telling you to stop using AI to answer, FWIW a Moderator told you it's OK as long as you review AI answers to follow the "answer rules". But the answers weren't and hence got curated, like everyone else's.

Comment: Although in my very honest opinion, the main core of the problem is another 
type of "stackoverflow is toxic", when new contributors wanted to accomplish what they wanted to do disregarding the rules.

Comment: Coming back to this discussion the next day, and in light of the story you've posted to your profile, I feel like the intention was never to _help people_ or _contribute meaningfully_ to Stack Overflow. You just wanted somewhere to experiment with your AI and are upset we don't want to be your guinea pigs.

Comment: You were told in no uncertain terms that _your_ contributions as a _human_ were very welcome here, yet you want to cry persecution that we're "not welcoming". IMO this is the experience of 100% of people who claim that SO is "toxic" -- you're just upset you weren't allowed to participate _your_ way

Comment: Considering the changes to the OP's profile, it seems that they actually had no intention of learning from their mistakes, or understanding the reasons why their content wasn't allowed. Disappointing... As I mentioned before, I suspect they (as a human) they could have made some great contributions.

Comment: I think you miss one important point: the AI ban isn't because it is AI. No one has something against useful tools. On the contrary, there are many useful tools our there like SmokeDetector that the community loves and uses. The problem with AI answers is that they are often *bad* or just *wrong* and *improperly vetted*, thus, doing more harm then good because they *look* correct at first glance and might mislead users. The ban on AI is to help making sure users get actual, useful help. That has always been the goal, and I think everyone would *love* it if AI can be used to make that easier.

Comment: "How is this any different than a real software development job?" - for starters, a real software developer tests their code _before_ releasing it, instead of throwing AI generated crap at the customer and then waiting for bug reports to come in...

Comment: Most of the comments here seem to be constructive, there might be some that come off a bit accusatory, but lets keep in mind tone is difficult to decipher on the internet. Your profile currently seems to be doing the very thing you are accusing other users to have done (disrespecting and accusing other users).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat You might not know this as I deleted my comments but go look at the edits when people said something sounded rude or was unneeded I changed it. No one is asking people to be perfect, and I am not pretending to be perfect. Its almost like conversation works....

Comment: In skimming this, I believe that you've said plenty on your perspective and where you stand on the matter, and the community has also voiced their reaction and opinion to where you stand on the matter as well.  I don't...really see a lot of value in continuing to brow-beat people in edits to your main question as responses to comments.  If you as a human want to continue to contribute to the site, you're welcome to do so, but we have made our opinion about incorporating AI crystal clear to you.

Comment: Oh wow, you just played the victim card in your profile...

Mate, the ___entire___ negative attitude to you is because of your toxicity in your answer and comments.

Comment: \*[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/) (not *stack overflow*). Three instances.