# Shouldn't users be citing ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, rules, chatgpt

I know this sounds counterintuitive, who would out themselves? We are all aware of the [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1). However, this post has to do with the plagiarism aspect of using ChatGPT.

While it is a bannable offense to post content from ChatGPT (the first offense seemingly being a week suspension at the time of writing), it seems we would benefit from discussing the plagiarism involved in posting material from ChatGPT.

Posting entirely from ChatGPT is one thing, and a week suspension is a nice slap on the wrist for that which will hopefully educate users on the policy. However, copy pasting content from another tool without citing it is plagiarism.

Should there also be additional penalties for users plagiarizing ChatGPT, meaning that they posted the content which was not authored by them without citing its source?

For example, let's say I were to include a paragraph from ChatGPT. I asked it to write an example blurb for meta Stack Overflow and it gave me this:

> As Stack Overflow continues to grow, effective question tagging is becoming increasingly important. Tagging helps users find the information they need and ensures that experts can quickly locate questions within their area of expertise. -ChatGPT Feb 13 Version.

Shouldn't this be cited (proper or different citation can be debated), as sourced from ChatGPT, in order to avoid plagiarizing the tool or its sources?

OpenAI's user policy does state that it should be, as was also linked in [Makoto's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421856/1026459) in the original banning post, https://openai.com/api/policies/sharing-publication/#content-co-authored-with-the-openai-api-policy.

> Creators who wish to publish their first-party written content (e.g., a book, compendium of short stories) created in part with the OpenAI API are permitted to do so under the following conditions:
>
> - The published content is attributed to your name or company.
> - The role of AI in formulating the content is clearly disclosed in a way that no reader could possibly miss, and that a typical reader would find sufficiently easy to understand.
> - Topics of the content do not violate OpenAI’s Content Policy or Terms of Use, e.g., are not related to political campaigns, adult content, spam, hateful content, content that incites violence, or other uses that may cause social harm.
> - We kindly ask that you refrain from sharing outputs that may offend others.

Outright 100% reproduction of ChatGPT should still be banned in my opinion.

That said, it seems it is proper to cite this type of content, and it would also make it easier to recognize when posted. Perhaps citing it could also lead to a situation where partial inclusion was perhaps not as problematic as when authors attempt to claim they wrote the entire response.

Comment: It's not our (or SO's) place to enforce policies from other sources. That said, we can and should enforce our own. Given that these users are suspended for a lengthy amount of time and have all of their chatgpt posts deleted, I'm not sure what an additional penalty would really do

Comment: Output from ChatGPT has no copyright, as only a human can produce a work with copyright, a computer ML program cannot, nor can a monkey. The most OpenAI can do is kick you off their platform, they don't own any copyright to the output of ChatGPT. Plagiarism is stealing someone else's work, but ChatGPT legally isn't 'someone'.

Comment: @KevinB - It isn't really enforcing another sources policy, so much as noting that it isn't just free form content. Also, week isn't really a lengthy amount of time.

Comment: @vandench - Note that the requirement is to cite the source and role, not necessarily claim ownership of the content.

Comment: Let me put it another way. You're effectively suggesting users who don't openly disclose that they are violating our policies should receive a stronger penalty, yea? doesn't that sound a bit silly? I mean, if we ever dropped the ban i could see putting in that kind of rule... but we're not there yet.

Comment: @vandench That being said, any content ChatGPT generates itself is almost certainly guaranteed to be in violation of copyright _itself_ since the data it was trained on was  certainly not entirely legally consumed.

Comment: I can honestly say I haven't seen a single user who has posted ChatGPT content clearly state that the the content was generated by ChatGPT. *If*, and only ***IF***, users start doing that I don't see any benefit of even thinking about whether an answer that contains attributed ChatGPT vomit is "ok", because I don't believe that such users ever *will* be honest about it. The fact that the users don't check the work before they post the (unattributed text) is another problem that needs to be solved before we consider this.

Comment: @KevinB - No, it does not. At least if you cite it and use a narrow version of the content an argument can be made to whether the post originated entirely from ChatGPT versus merely using a small portion. If users intend to pass themselves off entirely as ChatGPT, then a 1 week ban doesn't seem effective, as this content is everywhere right now.

Comment: @Larnu - That's a fair take, but it is also still analyzing that the post is entirely sourced from ChatGPT, which as I state above should be banned. Mostly, this is to address the possibility of including small portions, which would or should have been author reviewed.

Comment: There's no value in that content existing, if it isn't the primary content of the answer. Saying "Chatgpt said X" provides no value whatsoever in an answer. In a question, I don't think it's strictly forbidden to include a wrong answer from chatgpt when including things you've tried

Comment: I'm not saying I *disagree* with the idea, however, I feel that the suggestion is a little putting the cart before the horse. We need the users to *learn* to crawl (cite properly), walk (test), and run (add their own user contrnt) to allow this, and they haven't learned how to crawl yet.

Comment: there's no value whatesoever in using chatgpt as a reliable source worth citing, a good answer would never use chatgpt as a source because a good answer would have it's answerer and official documentation as sources, not a chatbot. I see no value in even creating a policy that suggests answerers should cite chatgpt content.

Comment: @TylerH I don't believe the courts have made a ruling on that yet. And even if they did, the copyright holder would still need to show that the output from ChatGPT is substantively based on the work of the copyright holder. Given the text is generative, it's going to be rather hard in most cases for someone to try and claim copyright infringement on the output. Also, to the best of my knowledge, the currently active lawsuits are around image generators, which have a tendency to produce works that are very clearly derivative of a specific artist.

Comment: @KevinB - If you feel strongly, please place your response as an answer so it doesn't clutter the comments. It needs its own area for discussion other than here. That is why I posted this as a question, instead of just randomly commenting below one of your posts.

Comment: @KevinB - ChatGPT is good at cross referencing, which is something that is lacking in many spaces. It can be a useful tool in narrow spaces.

Comment: I don't care if it's all the vomit that ChatGPT generates or just a cup of the vomit, the content ChatGPT generates is complete garbage.  I have yet to see a answer, generated by ChatGPT, that wasn't complete and total garbage.  I have identified at least 3 dozen answers generated by ChatGPT.  ChatGPT sucks at identifying context, so it often attempts to answer a question on a different subject, than what the actual question was asking about.  Only a human is able link two subjects, and determine from the context, what the actual topic of the question is.

Comment: @SecurityHound - It does suck at detecting context from a single interaction. It requires a priming in order to build context, a hand holding if you will, prior to any real production.

Comment: @vandench You don't need a court ruling to know they stole content without proper attribution or permission, let alone violating users' privacy. There are gazillions of blogs and articles out there that document how it did so. In fact I think GPT-3's authors itself even acknowledge this.

Comment: @TylerH - Sadly, not a single person who has used it and then submitted content, has actually done that.

Comment: @TylerH The dispute would not be over whether works from people was used without permission, that is an undisputed fact. That dispute would be whether it falls under fair use, and part of determining fair use is determining how much of the original work was used in the derivative work. Like I said before, you would need someone to file specific claim against a specific output, based on a specific work they had created. Without that, it's just a work of art, created by a computer, for which no one holds a copyright to, and isn't possible to plagiarize, as it legally wasn't created by anyone.

Comment: I would like to say one thing: ChatGPT is not guaranteed "vomit", to follow the terminology used here. I have seen plenty of seasoned veterans use ChatGPT really effectively to the point where it scares me since I myself cannot, I think I'm missing some classic engineering training in my education. It is how the average Stack Overflow visitor would use it (lazily) that makes it crap.

Comment: @ThomA The ones that use AI responsibly are honest about it, like myself, but the consequence with current policies is that perfectly legit & verified answers that are mostly human-written but mention ChatGPT get deleted, which is kind of fucked up... Like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using (now rewritten a bit & reposted). Or don't get upvoted like here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than/618452#618452

Comment: @TomWenseleers It *is* a bit messed up. Unfortunately, the *vast majority* use it irresponsibly. We *can't* sift through the content to try to find the <1% who might have used it responsibly. Even if we *could* do that, we shouldn't need to spend *huge* amounts of volunteer time to do so. We also *can't* trust people to be honest about it, because a large percentage of people who use it irresponsibly *demonstrably lie*, even ones specifically advocating for responsible use of AI generation (not you, another user posting on MSO). So, yes, "this is why we can't have nice things."

Comment: @Makyen Still feel that organising a GPT witchhunt is a very bad idea. Especially given that the output of ChatGPT4 frequently now is at least on a par with the average user response. Using some input from ChatGPT4 can typically only improve answers, not make them worse. Telling if an answer is correct is typically easy, detecting GPT if undisclosed is hard or impossible. Clear guidelines on accepted or disallowed use would solve a lot of problems. Like in those PNAS guidelines. GPT will not go away. Would be a great opportunity in fact to use it to help answer many unanswered questions on SO.

Comment: @Makyen You are vastly overestimating the average quality of the average human-written answer. Take the answer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412580/why-is-r2-not-reported-for-glms-based-on-last-iteration-of-irls-weighted-least-s for which I gave a bounty. That would qualify as a "human hallucination". Answer of ChatGPT4 was 1000x better - it reasoned about the pros and cons of these different R2 metrics, their theoretical properties, etc... If no one else replies I think that would be checked as the correct answer, would it?

Comment: _"Especially given that the output of ChatGPT4 frequently now is at least on a par with the average user response."_ You keep repeating this nonsense based on your limited use. GPT output still has the same exact limitations it's always had. It's mediocre ___at best___. Sure, it can get lucky, but it's unreliable, and inconsistent!

Comment: @TomWenseleers that comment is 4 months old, and at the time of writing was correct. I can confirm that at this time of writing that I can count the number of answers I've seen that state their answer is wholely GPT written is countable with the fingers on either of my hands; you can choose which hand if you prefer, but they both have 4 fingers (and a thumb, obviously, but that's not a finger :) ).

Comment: @ThomA For ChatGPT3.5 I would have agreed & so yes that was before ChatGPT4. But not for ChatGPT4. This answer was practically completely written by it https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than and this was not a lucky shot no, I've been using this for months, daily. Have you?

Comment: @ThomA This is how ChatGPT4 scores on university entrance exams. This is not the score you can get by bullshitting - it would actually be enough to let you in at Stanford or MIT... https://www.semafor.com/article/03/15/2023/how-gpt-4-performed-in-academic-exams

Comment: @TomWenseleers No, no I'm not overestimating the average quality of the average human-written answer. The *difference* is that the *vast majority* of poor-quality, human-created answers can be determined to be poor quality by merely glancing at them and that determination can be done, *most of the time*, by people with little or no subject-matter expertise. It also takes notable *time* for a human to create those answers. In contrast, AI-generated content takes *seconds* to create each one and is typically "eloquent bullshit" which takes *significant time to evaluate* [continued]

Comment: [continued] and *often* needs a notable amount of subject matter expertise. The *human resource cost* to our volunteers is *orders of magnitude higher* to evaluate average, poor-quality, AI-generated content than it is to evaluate average, poor-quality, human-generated content, **and** that poor-quality, AI-generated content can be generated *orders of magnitude faster* than the human-generated content. We *just don't have* and *can't get* the *orders of magnitude* more human resources, particularly subject matter experts, in order to do the evaluation of AI generated content quality at scale.

Comment: @Makyen I might agree for parts of Stack Overflow (e.g. those based on particular very specific factual information), but not for programming related answers where it would be easy to only allow usage where reproducible code should be required plus output. This alone would prevent people from posting non-working ChatGPT code. Effort to determine that, e.g. for https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/ridge-regression-in-r-where-coefficients-are-penalized-toward-numbers-other-than less than telling it might be written with GPT...

Comment: To be frank, I don't care how GPT scores on an exam, it's not a human, @TomWenseleers . When AI has come along enough to have rights and interact with the real world, let me know. Then, maybe, they'll be able to answer on [so].

Comment: I'm honestly wondering if Tom is invested (financially) in the success of this technology, considering the lengths they go. That, or trolling (as they know how much the technology has been rejected here due to users plagiarising its output).

Comment: @TomWenseleers For a *subject mater expert* (SME), it might not take as much time for a particular answer. However, it often *does* take significant time, even for an SME and even for the subset which you've defined (where they might have to take the time to set up and run the code).

Comment: @Makyen First: of course I have no financial interest in this. I am just an academic that uses ChatGPT to get on with my work (mainly programming in R). But there was such a huge gap between my experience & what I see posted here that I felt obliged to reply & share my experience using it. Also citing a couple of answers where I did post a ChatGPT answer, cf https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348. It may be a factor that as a subject matter expert I do know what questions to ask yes.

Comment: @Makyen Some argue that if you include all the prompting that the final code that comes out of ChatGPT then has become your own work & hence also shouldn't be disclosed & can be used as inspiration for a Stack Overflow answer. But I still find all the policies on this terribly opaque (eg also when using Github Copilot to write part of your code - some say blanket ban, others say OK if used as part of an answer & well tested etc). I hope it will all become clearer over time...

Comment: @TomWenseleers I can understand that there's consternation. What we, humans, are going through is a societal shift surrounding "AI" technology (in quotes, because it's really just machine learning using a large language model, not *real* artificial intelligence). That societal shift/adjustment is in process and will remain in process for, probably, years, particularly because the technology *will* improve. It's likely that what our societies accept as one's own work will be redefined, at least somewhat, but that hasn't happened, yet (by a considerable margin).

Comment: @Makyen Well I've seen the opinion on generative AI already shift completely at the university where I work & in academia more generally. While GPT3 was still too unreliable, most then cautioned against its use & some even went in the direction of a ban. After the release of ChatGPT4 things shifted completely & the university now is wholly supportive & stimulates everyone to use it, also as part of the courses for the students & emphasizes responsible AI use, e.g. transparency, validation, etc. Same for most journals. But already big productivity benefits in many fields of science.

Comment: So your uni is just blindly following the AI train because it's got a new version number. The differences aren't that significant. But why do I even bother telling you that for the 10th time? How do you not see this is just people that don't understand the limitations of AI, pushing for the use of AI? It's infuriating! All aboard the hype train, sheesh.

Comment: @TomWenseleers To be clear: I didn't imply, or even consider, that you might have a financial motive. While there has been at least one person advocating for AI generated content here who did have a financial stake in the AI industry (and I'm sure there are others on both sides, because how could there not be), nearly everyone is arguing out of their sincerely held beliefs. It definitely doesn't take having a financial stake in AI to have the opinions you're sharing. [In fact, I considered deleting that comment by someone else, but I'm currently on strike, so not doing any moderation.]

Comment: It's not a hype @Cerbrus - if you think at this stage that it's nothing more than a stochastic parrot etc then you just haven't spent enough time learning to use these systems. I would have agreed on many of the points raised for the early versions, but not for the latest one. Claiming they are all just the same is just disingeneous. My uni is teaching its personnel & students to use this technology responsibly, incl. recognising its limitations. SO would do well to also go down that route eventually...

Comment: Let me be honest, @TomWenseleers , if GPT, or similar technology, can pass a university test or provide a high quality essay, doesn't matter to me in many places, [so] included. If someone can take the output of GPT and pass it as their own that's a major concern as this does not demonstrate understanding or learning. For users seeking answers, who post questions here, they may well learn from the answer but the person who posted it? They likely know very little. Even on [so] that impact can be huge. Now imagine if your surgeon got their qualifications by plagiarising GPT generated content.

Comment: @ThomA I can attest that I learn a hell of a lot from asking things to ChatGPT and asking follow up questions and so on (it often directs me to new statistical techniques I didn't know about, solves mathematical problems for me, points me at ways to solve a problem etc). It stimulates your thinking a lot more than just by Googling. It also helps to organise your own thinking. It's also very good at rephrasing a poorly worded answer or question. And there is still a big creative aspect in all of this too: you still need to ask intelligent questions...

Comment: You're just using it as a glorified search engine then... At the risk of it confidentially spouting falsehoods and you not realizing it is.

Comment: @Tom Wenseleers: Re *"solves mathematical problems"*: I don't have access to GPT-4, but I got three different answers to *"What are the prime factors of 92001?"* (exact prompt, but the verbose answers are not included here, just the result)): beginning of March 2023: *"92001 = 3 x 7 x 1381"* (off by a factor of about 3.17.). On 2023-05-12: *"13 x 709"* (off by factor of about 9.98). On 2023-06-17 (today): *"7 × 17 × 19 × 31"* (off by about 31%). The correct answer is 3 × 7 × 13 × 337. (92001 was the number of sectors on a particular SSD drive excluding prime factors "2" )

Comment: @PeterMortensen ChatGPT3.5 was crap at math. But ChatGPT4 with the Wolfram Alpha plugin gives you the correct result: "The prime factors of 92001 are 3, 7, 13, and 337.". All of the info on ChatGPT here on SO is terribly outdated. Have a look at these examples https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm definitely not using it as a glorified search engine. Google can't program yet as far as I know. Just take a look at some of the examples I posted here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348

Comment: @Cerbrus Any info you pick up from somewhere you need to look at with a critical eye. Anything that comes out of GPT. Certainly the stuff I read on Stack Overflow. But for that matter any published article as well. No one is infallible. Many human experts can sound convincing but be dead wrong... But the fact that one can have extended conversations & discussions with ChatGPT makes it really powerful.

Comment: Sigh. 28 comments, 0 answers. **That** is, as you say, fucked up. This isn't a personal blog, or twitter, or whatever other thread based forum people go on and on about in tangential discussion. Take it to chat. If you use ChatGPT you are obligated, by OpenAI, to cite it. If you write something here which is not your own, you are obligated, by Stack Overflow's user agreement, to cite it. Not doing so is subject to corrective action. Full Stop. You would think a so called academic would understand the need for integrity and honesty.

Comment: You are so darn blind to the limitations of language models... It's absurd.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## All AI generated content is "the work of others" and *requires* following the [referencing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

This is Stack Overflow's, the company's, policy as explained by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) in [answer to: "Is attribution required for machine-generated text when posting on Stack Exchange?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384648/271271) and applies to all Stack Exchange sites, including Stack Overflow.

This is *regardless* of the copyright status of the AI content.

It was initially established for Stack Overflow, the site, in the consensus in [answer to: "Is it acceptable to post answers generated by an AI, such as GitHub Copilot?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412702/3773011).

This means [you need to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing):

> If you copy (or closely rephrase/reword) content that you did not create into something you post on Stack Overflow (e.g., from another site or elsewhere on Stack Overflow), make sure you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) to the original page or answer
> - [Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

##### Note: "[Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/3773011)" and "[Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)" still apply, so *even if it's only a portion of the post and is properly referenced*, content generated by ChatGPT is still banned.

Trivia: In my experience, about 99.9% of the ChatGPT generated content that's posted on Stack Overflow doesn't follow the referencing requirements.

Comment: "Trivia: In my experience, about 99.9% of the ChatGPT generated content that's posted on Stack Overflow doesn't follow the referencing requirements." : I wonder why - the ones that do use AI responsibly, like myself, and disclose how they used it & what steps were taken to verify correctness of the result, get their answers deleted right away... Like for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using/76472961?noredirect=1#comment134865427_76472961

Comment: @TomWenseleers That argument just indicates that you, along with others, are not willing to follow the rules, *just because you don't want to*. So, your own argument *proves the point* that some of the users who want to do this *don't* and *won't* follow the rules. However, you're right that to make what I said more relevant, I should have made it clear that my 99.9% statement was actually talking about posts which were posted during the time prior to the complete ban when only the referencing requirements applied. So, your argument is actually inapplicable.

Comment: It principally illustrates the ambiguity of the rules (by what % can an answer be based on or inspired by something from ChatGPT4)... With current policies it is clear that no one will ever disclose use of GPT yes. Which differs from the policies of a large nr of academic journals now, e.g. https://www.pnas.org/post/update/pnas-policy-for-chatgpt-generative-ai

Answer (score 9):

There is no value in having a policy specific to ChatGPT requiring citing sources. We already have such a policy for the general case.

That said, there's also no value in ChatGPT answers being provided *as* sources because a valuable answer would be citing reputable sources, not a chat bot. Citing ChatGPT in a given answer would literally do the answer harm in terms of whether or not it is a good reputable answer.

I wouldn't necessarily be against users pointing out when they've relied upon ChatGPT to generate an answer, however that should only lead to its deletion if they're using it as a source of information.

Comment: I agree with almost all of what you are saying here, except for the one aspect I was hoping to discuss in this post. Namely, this situation where only a single blurb comes from ChatGPT. As an example, a primary source of some of the learning from ChatGPT came from w3schools. That isn't really a good endorsement, if you are familiar with that as a source, however, it does produce the very similar guidance on simple subjects. Including a small phrase of explanation there to accompany the use in code whereby the answerer wrote their own code and also explains the code is perhaps beneficial.

Comment: My concern is that entirely banning all versions of content from ChatGPT is going to become extremely burdensome to our moderation team here. It may be extremely difficult to detect if it is remixed into only part of posts. In that regard, perhaps it makes more sense to at least provide guidance for proper use.

Comment: my argument is, it would be more beneficial to cite w3schools in that case than it would be to cite chatgpt.

Comment: I would say yes if it were a direct citation. However, ChatGPT does at times provide a composite of several sources in a condensed form which can be more efficient to use. It also does not disclose where its information comes from (which imo is a separate but problematic issue).

Comment: The consequence - users that use AI responsibly & properly cite their sources - get their answers deleted right away. And the answer from the ones using it irresponsibly, not citing their source, remain resulting in observation above: "Trivia: In my experience, about 99.9% of the ChatGPT generated content that's posted on Stack Overflow doesn't follow the referencing requirements."

Answer (score 5):

So I'm gonna get pretty rules-laywer-y on this.  Let me state up front, from what I've considered presented here:

- Not ascribing your sources is plagiarism, and plagiarism is not allowed anywhere in the network.
- Having a user cite that they got their information from Source X is pretty routine stuff in the normal swing of things.

What I can't really offer is if citing that you got your answer from ChatGPT makes the thing *better™*.

---

Let's take this part by part.  The policy on why ChatGPT is banned is as follows, emphasis mine.

> **The primary problem is that while the answers which ChatGPT produces have a high rate of being incorrect, they typically look like they might be good and the answers are very easy to produce.** There are also many people trying out ChatGPT to create answers, without the expertise or willingness to verify that the answer is correct prior to posting. **Because such answers are so easy to produce, a large number of people are posting a lot of answers.** The volume of these answers (thousands) and the fact that the answers often require a detailed read by **someone with at least some subject matter expertise in order to determine that the answer is actually bad** has effectively swamped our volunteer-based quality curation infrastructure.

In reading this, the main justification as to why ChatGPT is banned is centered around two factors:

- Correctness of answers
- Volume of answers

In short, we're getting bombarded by a deluge of crap answers.  People deciding to cite their work on that isn't really going to improve matters too much and it wouldn't really tip the scale in one direction or another on people's use of the tool.

---

Let's take away factor 1 from this equation - let's say that there is a "correct" answer that is generated by ChatGPT.  In that context, not citing your source is still tantamount to plagiarism, and there's just no guarantee that this makes the situation any better to what's already going on.  At best, the community loses something useful because someone took something else's work and tried to pass it off as their own.  At worst (and I mean this is worst case scenario, so hyperbole abounds) we now have people with whole site curator powers who are not expert enough to help the community identify issues with answers at any sensible scale.

---

Not that long ago [we had someone try to do this thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422951/1079354) where they walked the tightrope between having AI-generated answers and human curated responses.  It fell flat on its face because the human didn't human, and I don't recall their answer having the right citations attached.  Let's suppose then that this person *had* done all of the things correct:

- They had properly attributed their answer to ChatGPT in the manner required,
- They had curated it for correctness and indicated that they had proofread it, *and*
- The answer was good and useful for others.

On its face this avoids the reason that ChatGPT was disallowed in the first place:

- The answer was validated to be correct, and
- the volume of answers provided to the site is low per capita.

*However*, this highlights another issue which I touched on earlier - you're giving someone powers and privilege on the site who doesn't really have the same level of expertise as someone who doesn't use ChatGPT.

---

So all in all, I'm not sure if this makes the situation any better.  Even if users cited that they got their information from ChatGPT, and even if the answer was correct, there's a different problem brewing behind that which the original policy doesn't cover, either in spirit or in letter, which would require some *extra* thinking.

For all I know, maybe Stack Overflow *doesn't* care if a person really knows what they're talking about.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This is essentially right where my thinking is too. The aspect of site privilege is an interesting one that I hadn't considered. I guess I just thought that anyone able to accurately glean information that was correct would also have a high level of subject knowledge.