# How should answers citing ChatGPT be flagged?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, chatgpt

Since the introduction of the plagiarized content flag, I've been steadily using it to flag answers clearly generated by ChatGPT (by clearly I mean I've gone to ChatGPT and had a chance to produce very similar answer using a couple of first sentences of the question).

But even within this short time I've encountered a couple of instances when the author flat out admits that answer was generated by ChatGPT. I believe such an answer should not be counted a plagiarism, but still should be deleted.

As a result, I flagged those posts as "In need of moderator intervention" and explained my position.

My understanding is that "In need of moderator intervention" has the highest priority, but in my honest opinion answers generated by ChatGPT don't deserve this priority.

###### TL;DR

Should I use the plagiarized content flag when the author admits their answer is generated by ChatGPT or should I keep using intervention flag for this?

P.S. I've seen question [Shouldn't users be citing ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423407/shouldnt-users-be-citing-chatgpt), but I believe it was not updated since introduction of the plagiarized flag.

Comment: [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423749/plagiarism-flag-and-moderator-tooling-has-launched-to-stack-overflow#comment950923_423749) on the subject: *"I'd still use a custom flag for ChatGPT answers at this stage."*

Comment: Side note, *In need of moderator intervention* don't have the highest priority. I believe both *Spam* and *Rude and Abusive* are generally handled with a higher priority.

Comment: "*I've seen question Shouldn't users be citing ChatGPT?, but I believe it was not updated since introduction of plagiarized flag.*" because [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) still applies. Which the accepted answer by Makyen points out **very explicitly with a larger font and bold text**.

Comment: "*IMHO answers generated by chatGPT don't deserve this priority.*" again...see the policy on ChatGPT answer which are *very explicitly banned*.

Comment: @VLAZ, I agree that they are explicitly banned (and for good). My question is merely what flag should be used to highlight those posts for mods. Obviously I completely missed cited commend of ChrisF.

Comment: Is it really plagiarism if you copy something which was not published? Output from ChatGPT is not published. I think AI-generated and plagiarized are two different things. AI-generated often being low quality content, while plagiarized posts are often (taken from) high quality content.

Comment: @Lundin here is the definition of plagiarism: _the practice of taking someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own_. Taking something written by ChatGPT and claiming it to be your own is plagiarism, even if it isn’t published. However, it doesn’t really matter as ChatGPT (and other AIs) are [currently banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035).

Comment: Related: [What should I do if I suspect that a question or answer is written by ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421988/4518341) The answer is the same ("In need of moderator intervention"), but the question was posted before the plagiarism flag launched, so the intricacies are a little different.

Comment: If I drive 100 on the highway but have a bumper sticker that cites the relevant law, are the police still allowed to issue me a citation? :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) answered this in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423749/plagiarism-flag-and-moderator-tooling-has-launched-to-stack-overflow#comment950923_423749) on the [Plagiarism flag annoucement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423749/plagiarism-flag-and-moderator-tooling-has-launched-to-stack-overflow):

> I'd still use a custom flag for ChatGPT answers at this stage.

So regardless of if the post properly cited the content in a quote block and states it was generated by ChatGPT or not, you should flag the post using an **In need of moderator intervention**, aka "custom", flag. *All* [AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/2029983) [are banned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy), regardless of intent from the user who posted it. This is true for *any* content generated by AI, *not* just ChatGPT.

When you raise the flag, ensure you explain why you are flagging the post (it appears to be ChatGPT content) and why you feel it's ChatGPT content. The Mods have additional tools and workflows that they use to confirm, or at least justify, your suspicions.

Plagiarism flags should be used for content which is copied from non-AI generated sources such as other answers, online articles, documentation, books, etc, and the user does not follow the [referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) (doesn't use quoteblocks, doesn't cite **both** the author (where available) *and* original source, and contains no original content).

Comment: Re *"Plagiarism flags should be used for content ... does not follow the referencing guidelines (doesn't use quoteblocks, doesn't cite both the author and original source, and contains no original content)."*: I think that is a fair (but very strict) guideline. However, very little content on Stack Overflow follow this guideline, incl. on highly upvoted answers from the early days. In fact, I don't think I have ***ever*** seen an answer following all of the guideline, in particular the author attribution one. What should we do? Perhaps add some action guideline to the answer?

Comment: Is there an exemplary Stack Overflow answer?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Generally, editing it to fix minor attribution issues is the ideal solution.  I've done that in a number of cases (including in questions, which _often_ fail to cite the source of code they're asking about).

Comment: *"Is there an exemplary Stack Overflow answer?"* If you check this answer, you'll see I did all 3 here, @PeterMortensen . I'm sure I could find some other examples where I do this in answers over on [main]. Note that the author isn't always accessible though; documentation for products is a frequent example of this.

Comment: Here is an example of such a highly upvoted answer from the early days that doesn't contain any original content (except for noting it applies to both both C and C++): [Robert S. Barnes's answer to *Why is volatile needed in C?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c/3308849#3308849). It is two walls of text (with source references) and the reader is left to figure out how it applies to the question.