# Editing a question to remove all its content after receiving an answer

Tags: support, edits, specific-question

I just came across this question with a weird title: [C# Challenge - Deleted Copyright Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50303252/4934172), so I opened it to find no content at all and that it just says:

> Deleted - copyright issue, not suppose to share publicly.

Is this behavior acceptable? The question has three answers already, two of them have 5 or more upvotes so removing the content of the question like this affects the value of the question *as well as the answers*.

Clearly, this was done as a way to get around the limitation of deleting questions with upvoted answers. So, my question is **what should I do in such a case?**

- Rollback the edit and explain to the user that this behavior is unacceptable and that he/she can flag the question so that [a moderator can hide confidential information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258070/4934172) (if any).
- Flag the question for a moderator intervention.
- Just let it go and excuse the user considering his action justified by the reason mentioned in the edit.

Comment: It has upvoted answers and an accept.  I rolled it back.  If SO staff wish/need to delete it because of a genuine copyright violation, court order, whatever, then fine.

Comment: If that content is in violation of copyright they could file a [DMCA](https://stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) request. I'm not sure if that works if they are not the copyright holder and are just trying to hide plagiarism or school assignments.

Comment: @rene I was about to roll the edit back actually but I just wanted to make sure it's the right thing to do. Should I leave a comment on that question with a link to this one so the OP knows his/her question is being discussed so that he/she can benefit from these suggestions?

Comment: Under the ToS it is stated that once posted they granted SE the irrevocable license to publish the content. Deleting it like they did is in violation of the ToS which is the reason rolling back such edits is allowed and your actions are covered. Most often the OP's don't like that outcome. So feel free to invite them but don't be surprised if you don't get cheered

Comment: Under section Subscriber Content [*You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any and all text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, animations, and product feedback (collectively, "Content") that you provide to the public Network (collectively, "Subscriber Content"), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow*](https://stackexchange.com/legal#licensing)

Comment: @rene wow, that's a bit...strange. Let's say I post some algorithm as an answer. A day later, I realise it's actually patented and thus should not have posted it. I am then unable to remove or change it. At the same time other people may have already used it without permission and I cannot even stop more people from using it. The only way to remove it would be for the IP holder to send a DMCA request to SO. It's a bit of an extreme example but still - core of the problem is that apparently I wouldn't be able to comply with copyright even if I want to.

Comment: @vlaz yeah, I didn't write the legal stuff but I don't think it is strange as content is the business model SO floats on. Don't post patented algorithms or any other stuff that isn't yours and / or should remain secret.

Comment: @rene it was a hypothetical example. I'd definitely try not to post copyrighted material but I might fail. Also, somebody else might fail and I might notice or vice versa. Bottom line is that the TOS makes it quite confusing to untangle once such a situation occurs. Even then, the only way to do it is to contact the IP holder who needs to step in.

Comment: @vlaz: Since the code was never yours to license to begin with, you never licensed it to [main], and they were never allowed to distribute it. *However*, they can a) argue good faith and b) sue you for any damage caused since you misrepresented yourself as being allowed to license the code to [main]. But in no way does this mean that you cannot get rid of that code any more, that would be ridiculous. As soon as [main] are notified that you made a mistake, they are no longer acting in good faith and *must* remove the content.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ah, thanks for the clarification. Reading the TOS led me to believe that anything I contribute is automatically considered to be licensed as CC and also property of SO, unless there is a DMCA request.

Comment: @vlaz: You cannot license something to [main] that you aren't allowed to license. Period. People make out copyright law as something ridiculously complicated, but really, it's as much common sense as any other law.

Comment: @JörgWMittag see, that's exactly what I thought, but the TOS wording confused me.

Comment: @vlaz: Look at this way: the TOS does not mean that anything you post automatically becomes licensed to [main] under CC. Rather, it means by posting something that you *cannot* license under CC, you violate the TOS (and are thus not allowed to post it). Since you violate the TOS, the TOS don't apply (otherwise you wouldn't be violating them).

Comment: If it worked the way you (mis)interpreted it, that would be a trivial loophole to open source anything and everything. Just set up a website which says "anything posted here is GPL", then bribe a Microsoft employee to anonymously post the Windows source.

Comment: I interviewed for a job and was asked to do an online assessment on Qualified.IO. I completed the assessment and failed this challenge. The challenge bothered me and hence posted here to get help in understanding how to solve it. The question I posted was directly from there. If the question can not be deleted, at least allow me the opportunity to rename variables, methods, classes and inputs - as I am suspect I may be in violation of Copyright issues.

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c You can do those kind of edits as long as you don't invalidate the answers.

Comment: @Rene "Under the ToS it is stated that once posted they granted SE the irrevocable license to publish the content." But only if they have the right to publish the content under such a license to begin with. Otherwise the original copyright holder could file a DMCA request and StackOverflow would have to take it down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first instance you should roll back the edit. However, don't sit on the question and start an edit war should the OP re-edit it. You could leave a comment reminding the user that they should edit the question to remove any copyright material, but that they shouldn't invalidate the answers.

If that happens then flag the question for moderator attention. Use the "other" option to explain exactly what's going on. We may already have the auto "rollback war" flag as well, but that depends on how the OP reacted. We'll take it from there.

Don't get involved in any arguments over the post.

Comment: _"Don't get involved in any arguments over the post."_ That should be Official Commenting Rule #2... It solves several questions I've read on Meta today...

Comment: This may solve this example, but is this the best strategy for such cases in general? What about flags for users that remove most content of a question after it has been answered? Or what if indeed the question mostly consisted of copyright material. Editing copyrighted material out wouldn't remove it from the edit history and a more forceful approach may be needed then.

Comment: @Trilarion, flagging for a moderator is generally a good approach. Moderators will presumably alert SO staff if necessary.