# Remove Sensitive Information From Questions - IP Addresses

Tags: discussion

I recently posted [a question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456913/aws-emr-shuffleerror) where I needed to paste a large amount of sever logs in the question. The server is an Elastic Map Reduce server (EMR) running in AWS that belongs to the company I work for. I stupidly didn't realize I kept the IP address of the server in the logs e.g., `[hadoop@ip-myIpAddressHere ~]$error line here`.

As you can see I replaced the IP address with myIpAddressHere but had I not caught it I'm wondering if someone could have exploited the server albeit unlikely. But in other scenarios if the question is about security configurations, or general server setup it may provide enough information for a malicious user to penetrate the site. The hacker would have the IP address and would have information on flaws pertaining to the server.

It seems like a simple program could detect IP addresses in Stackoverflow questions and warn the poster to remove them.

Comment: Not just ip's, one day i posted an online assay with a token, later i figured out that this token is a unique identifiant that can lead a curious to identify the e-mail, one should be considering these cases too.

Comment: Hmm, no, that stopped being a problem about a two decades ago.  When bots became common that try random IP addresses to find vulnerable machines.  They don't need an SO post to find such an address.  About the time I killed my FTP server, the soft-porn movie they figured out how to put on it wasn't that good.

Answer (score 3):

IPs aren't actually *that* dangerous as scanning the IPv4 range is a matter of hours nowadays.
What you may encounter instead are credentials or private tokens / keys posted with code.

> On my site example.com I can't connect to the DB?
>
> ```
> db.connect('admin', 'real looking password') // throws ObscureError
> ```

I've seen this a couple time before (desk and face still remember it).
It would be *very difficult* to code a way to detect all cases where this is an issue.<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>

For more information on how to handle them, see [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258066/4174897).

<sub><sup><sup>1</sup></sup>: [And if you feel like trying, here's your new home](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics)</sub>