# What is the SO policy on if a person exposes their username and password?

Tags: discussion, flags

I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318852/problem-with-inserting-data-into-the-database) recently where a user decided to post their credentials/information that could make them significantly vulnerable. The way I saw it, I had 4 options:

1. Edit it:

This is great, but my biggest problem with this is that the damaging information is still in the edit history, which anyone can read if they really want to hack someone (which a potential hacker would).

2. Vote to close/Flag for closure

I can't vote for closure yet, but I can still flag. My biggest problem with this is that a closed question still stays on the site, and can--again--still be seen by hackers.

3. Delete it

That's great, but I don't have the reputation to delete things yet.

4. Flag for moderator attention

Which is what I chose. This flag was marked as "helpful", and the question was edited by a moderator (which we can't see the history now, thankfully). Which tells me I was on the right track.

However, my question is two fold: 1) Was this the right decision, or is there something better I can do when I see questions like this as a general rule without bugging the moderators with a special flag? and 2) When I get the privilege to delete, should I just delete it instead, or still just flag it?

**EDIT:** This is absolutely a duplicate in substance, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258070/10957435) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317454/10957435) are probably the best answers in my opinion for anyone in the future who has this same problem...

Comment: Sure, but they're connecting to localhost, though.

Comment: (Unless Baum already redacted it.)

Comment: Yes, and I had [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253717/no-error-but-data-not-inserted-to-database-by-using-pdo#comment97239593_55253717) where they did the same thing for localhost. This one was different, however, because the question being asked. I was concerned that they might be asked the actual db/IP for legitimate purposes, or maybe even give it away accidentally for some reason. My point is that if I see someone who maybe hasn't connected to localhost, or their actual configuration might be necessary to properly answer the problem, how should I respond?

Comment: The dupe should answer that.  If it's localhost, I doubt we should really bother?