# How can I delete a question that I posted anonymously?

Tags: support, questions, anonymous-user, post-redaction

I accidentally added information that I did not intend to and would like for it to be deleted. Could you help me please?
[upgrading to sprinboot 2.5.12 and my Junit tests are throwing this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965370/upgrading-to-sprinboot-2-5-12-and-my-junit-tests-are-throwing-this-error)

Comment: You might want to ask them to delete the same information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71965370/3122701) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71995405/3122701) as well, as you seem to be asking about the same XML data in all three.

Answer (score 7):

There is no reason to delete the question. If there is sensitive information that you posted accidentally that you want to have removed/redacted, then flag the post for moderator attention and explain *specifically* what you want to have removed (and why).

See also: [How to handle a publicly posted API key (or password, or other sensitive information)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258066/how-to-handle-a-publicly-posted-api-key-or-password-or-other-sensitive-informa)